# How to pass value from one controller to two or more view in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I m working on a e commerce site with laravel 5.4 
Let's assume I have a ProductConttoller  and inside a showSingle($id) function.
I want pass value to the view of single product view with product details and wanna also pass the product title to a partial view _meta.blade.php

For single product view I am passing product value like

```
return view('product.show')->with product($product);
```

Now how to pass title/any meta to a different view like meta.blade.php

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you use the include function in your single product view.

So just do like that:

```
@include('_meta', ['title' => $product->title])
```

Or probably more easier, pass the entier product:

```
@include('_meta', ['product' => $product])
```

Then you can access any product properties from your _meta template.